# Why can't I see the "wget" job when I execute it in the background?

Tags: command-line, wget, background-process, job-control

I use `wget` command in the background like this

```
wget -bq
```

and it prints

> Continuing in background, pid 31754.

But when I type the command `jobs`, I don't see my job(although the downloading is not finished).

Comment: You can see it with `ps -p 31754`

Comment: `Jjobs` only works for the (this) shell job control (namely `&` annotation, ctrl-z or `bg` commamd). General process listing (`ps -a` will show it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using `wget` with `-b` or `--background` it puts *itself* into the background by disassociating from the current shell ([by forking off a child process and terminating the parent](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/tree/src/utils.c#n474)).  Since it's not the shell that puts it in the background as an asynchronous job, it will not show up as a job when you use `jobs`.

To run `wget` as an asynchronous (background) job in the shell, use

```
wget ... URL &
```

If you do this, you may additionally want to redirect output to some file (which `wget` does automatically with `-b`), or discard it by redirecting to `/dev/null`, or use `-q` or `--quiet`.

Comment: it forks a child and the parent exits

Comment: @user2497 Yes, see updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Because it put it self in the background. Use `&` to tell bash to put it into background, and to put it into bash's list of jobs.

Background and job control list are not the same. Bash puts all of its background processes into its jobs control list (by default), but processes can be backgrounded with out being put in the list. Only bash can put jobs in its list.

There may be advantages to the `-bg` option (I don't know what). For example `ssh`'s background option, puts it into the background after asking for a password.

Comment: It's `-bq`, i.e. `-b` and `-q`, not `-bg`.

Answer (score 2):

The process with pid 31754 exists; if you type `ps -e |grep 31754`  but as it is not a job that can be moved to the foreground again, it is not displayed by the jobs command. `wget -bq` automatically send the output to the background without options to move it to the foreground again.

Comment: `ps` has a `-p` option that can be used to query a specific PID, or one may use `pgrep wget`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `tail wget-log` to see the last few lines of the log thus giving me an idea of the status of the download.